# Tomcat server truststore root certificate

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat6, keystore

I need to trust a client certificate on my tomcat, I have added both the root (verisign) and customers domain certificate to the server truststore and it works fine and accepts the client connection.

Now the question is, does adding the root verisign cert to the truststore accept anything signed by that verisign cert? Or would that only be the case if I added it to the cacerts? Is it safe to leave it in the truststore?

I am using tomcat 6 and java 1.6 on linux

Thanks

Comment: Java Security By Scott Oaks tells me that I must have the root certificate of the CA in the truststore also so I will keep that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does adding the root verisign cert to the truststore accept anything signed by that verisign cert?

Yes it does. Your application still needs to perform an authorization step, based on the roles that are allocated to the user identified by the certificate. You shouldn't attempt to do that with the truststore and certificate alone, that's not the purpose of the mechanism. It is there for authentication. You are talking about authorization.

NB You are using your local truststore *instead of* the JRE's cacerts file.

Comment: That's perfect thanks EJP, we do have further authentication in the application but I guess it's preferable not to have the CA in the truststore anyway?

Comment: I think you need to have complete trust chain, it starts from CA.
Usual setup is: external CA - local CA - server - client. You can skip local CA if you need only one server and you do not have to issue client certificates if you do not have a use for them (e.g. for authenticating users with the certificate).

Comment: @kontiki You have to have whatever you need in the truststore to accept the client certificate. As part of the SSL handshake the server sends a list of root CAs that it trusts, which comes from the truststore, and the client sends its certificate chain up to and including the first root that it can see the server already trusts, but no further.